# Windows not booting anymore after using easyBcd

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, uefi, easybcd

I decided to install a dual boot on my windows 8.1 machine. Everything was working fine, but I had the unattractive grub booting option. I wanted to have the good-looking graphical windows boot selection to choose between windows and linux. I used easybcd on it and added a new entry for ubuntu, specifying the partition "/boot" that I had created when installing ubuntu. I applied the changes by clicking on Write MBR or similar option. And I now can't boot into Windows.

Here is the error displayed: http://i39.servimg.com/u/f39/13/84/06/30/10877310.jpg

What I have tried so far:
-Boot repair (recommended): didn't change it, except that I have more entries in grub
-Boot on a recovery key and run /fixmbr /fixboot

I ran the bootinfo script and I get this (quiet long sorry): http://pastebin.com/iqp4Jf25

Any idea how to recover boot options for windows ?
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: If it can help, I have this in my grub: http://i39.servimg.com/u/f39/13/84/06/30/img_2012.jpg

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a windows recovery disc.Cause there is an option of startup repair.

here's where you can get one-https://kickass.so/windows-7-x64-repair-disk-iso-t6446782.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I already tried this and when I'm in the right place to fix the startup, I only have ubuntu as a detected os: http://i39.servimg.com/u/f39/13/84/06/30/img_2011.jpg